# QGIS rasterize a styled layer

Tags: qgis, vector, style, rasterization

I disabled information from a vector layer with a styledefinition.
Is it possible to rasterize only the styled information in QGIS?

Comment: I think if you want to **rasterize** any vector layer, it must be based on an **attribute** of the vector layer and not on a style/visualisation. I could be wrong in which case others can provide expertly advice :)